# knockout mapping causes overwrites on prototype object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been getting a headache with this issue.

Basically i have the following  viewModel which has a derived class:

```
define(['./AViewModel'],function (aViewModel) {
    var newModel= function () {
        var self = this;
        this.Name = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });      
        });
    };

    newModel.prototype = Object.create(new baseViewModel);
    newModel.prototype.constructor = newModel;

    return newModel;
});
```

Then i am doing the following in a function

```
 var mappedData = [];
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (item) {
      var result = aFactory.create("newModel");
      var resultList = ko.mapping.fromJS(item, {}, result);
      mappedData.push(resultList);
});
 return tasks(mappedData);
```

But what is happening that the baseViewModel gets written everytime when added to the array. The newModel is ok.

Any ideas what could be causing this as it seems that the mapping for derived types does not work well when adding to an array.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, it's working as _I_ would expect it. Could you maybe reword your question or flesh out a more complete example? What do you mean by "the baseViewModel gets written everytime when added to the array?" Isn't it supposed to do that?

Comment: Hi when the newModel is new'd up it also adds the baseVIewModel. But when we use the knockout mapping it overwrites all the elements in the array with the current baseViewModel data. E.g. on the first loop the reference is ab12 for the baseViewModel. On the second liip the reference for baseVIewModel is ab13 but this object is overwritten on all the baseViewmodels in the array objects. It seems prototypes have one set instance which may be working as functional pointers.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue.  What happens in aFactory.create, that code seems to be where your problem occurs